# Textbox.Text has the wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that lists current projects, if you select one of the projects it loads the same page with a parameter and shows the users that belong to that project. For some reason it sometimes (depends on the project) shows the name of the project in the textbox where the username should be.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dbProxy = new DatabaseProxy();

        // No parameter, show project list
        if (this.Request.QueryString["ProjectID"] == null)
        {
            var user = new UserContainer();
            user.LoadUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

            List<ProjectContainer> projects = dbProxy.GetProjects(user.UserID, true);

            foreach (ProjectContainer project in projects)
            {
                var linkButton = new Button {Text = project.ProjectName};
                this.ProjectsPanel.Controls.Add(linkButton);
            }
        }
        // We have a parameter, show users for project
        else
        {
            int projectId = int.Parse(this.Request.QueryString["ProjectID"]);
            this.LoadUsers(projectId);
        }
    }
```

The LoadUsers function:

```
    private void LoadUsers(int projectId)
    {
        var databaseProxy = new DatabaseProxy();
        List<UserContainer> users = databaseProxy.GetUsersByProject(projectId);

        foreach (UserContainer user in users)
        {
            var txtUsername = new TextBox();
            txtUsername.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows projectname!
            var txtUsername2 = new TextBox();
            txtUsername2.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows username!

            this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername);
            this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername2);
        }
    }
```

The HTML code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditUsers.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxx.EditUsers1" MasterPageFile="PageStructure.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlace">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="padding-left: 25px">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 50px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text="Benutzer verwalten" CssClass="PageHeader"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="UserPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="ProjectsPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

The master page only contains a header and a footer and some JavaScript for a different page.

The output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p49jh.png

The user variable contains the right values and nothing more happens after LoadUsers. I can even add an empty label as first element, then it will show the correct username in the first textbox! I don't know why, but it just looks like it really wants the project name in the first element I add.

Example how it works, too:

```
    private void LoadUsers(int projectId)
    {
        var databaseProxy = new DatabaseProxy();
        List<UserContainer> users = databaseProxy.GetUsersByProject(projectId);

        foreach (UserContainer user in users)
        {
            var lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = ""; <- Stays invisible!
            var txtUsername = new TextBox();
            txtUsername.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows username!
            var txtUsername2 = new TextBox();
            txtUsername2.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows username!

            this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
            this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername);
            this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername2);
        }
    }
```

I guess I could find a workaround, like splitting it in two different web forms, but I still would like to know why I get the wrong value.

Comment: can you pls also post your html code? Is there any js that might cause this?

Comment: So you put the same username in both controls?

Comment: @Steve: Just for testing and to show that they contain different values though it comes from the same source. At the end I only want one textbox.

Comment: if you debug the code step by step, what value is in `txtUsername.Text`, can you try to run the page without js

Comment: AS is, the only possibility is that something change the content of the txtUserName textbox, try to search for that name everywhere in your solution

Comment: @Uriel_SVK: It has the correct value the whole time. Step by step it ends after LoadUser(), nothing more.

Comment: @Steve: I find txtUsername exact two times in the whole solution. Setting the text and adding it to the panel.

Comment: It must have to do with databinding, when are you databinding yuor page?

Comment: @Derek: Never, I didn't use databinding.

Comment: Can you _clear_ the controls in `this.UserPanel.Controls` and `this.ProjectsPanel.Controls` at the beginning of your page load event and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Can you try it in Chrome - press `F12` for developer console, click `Network`, reload your page. First should be html for your page. Can you pls check what value there is?

Comment: Debug your code, look at List<UserContainer> users in the watch window,  when its populated and look at the different objects it lists.. its the only way you can get to the bottom of the problem. Correct me if i'm wrong, but all asp.net web forms databind, unless you are using MVC?

Comment: @SFLee: Clearing doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Derek: The list has the correct values, I've stepped through every single step and checked the list and the variables inside. They contain the correct values. I don't know about databinding, but I didn't do it manually and I don't see any other place where a databinding would happen. I create everything manually.

Comment: @Uriel_SVK: The network tab says: <input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$ctl00" type="text" value="asdf" /><input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$ctl01" type="text" value="abc\testUser" /> (asdf is my test project)

Comment: Let's try something completely different... Can you try **refreshing** the (users) page on your web browser and see if it 'magically' fixes the problem?

Comment: Alright, let's try another magic... Can you disable the view state for that page? As in: `<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" ...%>`

Comment: What if you add an additional line `txtUsername.Name = "X" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");` before adding it to the panel? Do this for _both_ `txtUsername` and `txtUsername2`.

Comment: Also try this: Add the line `txtUsername.EnableViewState = false;` before adding the textbox into the panel. Again, do this for both `txtUsername` and `txtUsername2`.

Comment: @SFLee: I suppose you mean txtUsername.ID = "X"...? That actually worked! Aaaaah... so I guess the html name of the txt control was used as project control name!?

Comment: That was more like a hack. If the `txtUsername.EnableViewState = false;` works as well, it's better to use this. Let me know how it goes, then I'll write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by an out-of-sync view-state of the controls.

In ASP.NET, each form control has a view-state that keeps track of entered values so that when a page gets reloaded after a post-back, it can automatically fill in the previous values into each form control. Normally this will work fine, and is usually the desired behaviour. However, on some situations (like this one) where the controls are dynamically generated and their values got changed after returning from a post-back, then their view-states will end up overwriting the values and hence causing a problem.

To resolve this issue, either disable the post-back for the dynamically generated controls, like so:

```
foreach (UserContainer user in users)
{
    var txtUsername = new TextBox();
    txtUsername.EnableViewState = false;
    txtUsername.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows projectname!

    var txtUsername2 = new TextBox();
    txtUsername2.EnableViewState = false;
    txtUsername2.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows username!

    this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername);
    this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername2);
}
```

Or assign a different ID to each control each time it is generated so that the control will never match to the ID of the saved data in the viewstate, like so:

```
foreach (UserContainer user in users)
{
    var txtUsername = new TextBox();
    txtUsername.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    txtUsername.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows projectname!

    var txtUsername2 = new TextBox();
    txtUsername2.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    txtUsername2.EnableViewState = false;
    txtUsername2.Text = user.Username; // <- Shows username!

    this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername);
    this.UserPanel.Controls.Add(txtUsername2);
}
```

**Warning:** If you use either of the methods above, the values of the controls will not be sent back during a post-back or form submit. So any user-entered values in any of those controls will be lost. To avoid this problem, use Javascript to copy those values to a hidden control (that is **not** dynamically generated) on form submit. Or just simply don't use dynamically generated controls (if that is possible).

For more information on view-state vs dynamic controls, please check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've chosen to give a static ID as I may need to access the values later with JS.

Comment: mutter.  I'm getting this BEHAVIOUR (different cause) in the text boxes inside a list view (e.g. 0 instead of 404) where outputting the same value into HTML or another textbox shows the correct value.  It was happening for ALL rows, then after clearing the Temporary ASP.NET folder it now only happens on the first 2 rows (including if you filter and move rows from further down up into the 2 rows)  and of course, only on the production box.